# How do I change Postgresql to be listening on port 5432?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.6

I've upgraded Postgresql from 9.3 to 9.6 on my machine (linux mint rafaella- so ubuntu 14.04)

As the previous version was listening on 5432 the new version is listening on 5433, but I want to change that to 5432 so that the previous configuration (rails, phppgadmin etc) work with the new postgres server.

I have changed the port in postgresql.conf from 5433 to 5432 and restarted postgres, but this didn't work:

```
$ sudo netstat -nltp |grep 5432     
$ sudo netstat -nltp | grep 5433
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5433          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      25467/postgres
```

I also tried setting the environment variable and restarting postgres:

```
PGPORT=5432; export PGPORT
```

again, still listening on 5433 and nothing on 5432.

trying to connect gives me:

```
$ sudo -u postgres psql postgres 
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

What am I doing wrong?

Output of `pg_lsclusters`:

```
$ pg_lsclusters 
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory               Log file 
9.6 main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.6-main.log
```

contents of pg_hba.conf:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
local   all             postgres                                peer
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ running that gives me: $ pg_lsclusters
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory               Log file
9.6 main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.6-main.log

Comment: No -  psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
 Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Comment: @ypercube - they do yes.

Comment: I have edited the question to show pg_hba.conf

Comment: Discussion **[moved in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65425/discussion-between-ypercube-and-bigj).**

Answer (score 2):

[ypercube](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/9016/ypercube) and [deszo](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/43478/dezso) were able to get this user's environment up and running (per the chat transcript).

The key seemed to be running:

```
sudo pg_ctlcluster 9.6 main restart
```

but not running it as the postgres user.

See the [chat log](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65425/discussion-between-ypercube-and-bigj) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a line in your postgresql.conf file that says:

> port = 1486

Change that.

The location of the file can vary depending on your install options. On Debian-based distros it is

> /etc/postgresql/8.3/main/

On Windows it is

> C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\data

Comment: May be you could read the question again; the OP said he'd done that already.

Answer (score 0):

**As per `pg_lscluster` output :-**

It is showing port **5432** which indicate there is no other cluster of postgresql with port 5433.

Also `sudo -u postgres psql postgres` command output show :-

Your cluster **main** service is not running kindly restart that cluster using

`pg_ctlcluster 9.6 main restart  --if error post the log files`

- Also go to postgresql.conf file present in /etc/ find listen_address in it and set as per below
  `i.e listen_address='*'` and restart the service again .

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu 20.04 I solved it like this:

To list which ports is using:

```
sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
```

To list the paths of postgres and your respectives ports

```
grep -H '^port' /etc/postgresql/*/main/postgresql.conf
```

Choose the path of port you want change. In my case is

> /etc/postgresql/13/main/postgresql.conf

then I edit the configurations of port with:

```
sudo nano /etc/postgresql/13/main/postgresql.conf
```

Save the changes and restart the service with:

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

Then you can run `lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN` to see the ports is correctly.

Comment: Thanks, these commands were useful!